How do I filter XML nodes from SOAP response using XSLT
I have a situation where I need to filter certain XML nodes from SOAP response, I used XSLT mapping but it is not filtering specific xml nodes from SOAP Response, my requirement is to have xml node ns1:IntervalBlocks which has ns1:ReadingType ref="KWH_DEL" in the resulting XML, other ns1:IntervalBlocks should get removed
pls advise what is wrong in the logic
Here is my input xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns0:Message xmlns:ns0="http://www.iec.ch/TC57/2010/schema/message">
            <ns0:Payload>
                <ns1:MeterReadings xmlns:ns1="http://iec.ch/TC57/2011/MeterReadings#">
                    <ns1:MeterReading>
                        <ns1:IntervalBlocks>
                            <ns1:IntervalReadings>
                                <ns1:source>DR</ns1:source>
                                <ns1:value>6.112E0</ns1:value>
                                <ns1:ReadingQualities>
                                    <ns1:ReadingQualityType ref="ACTUAL"/>
                                </ns1:ReadingQualities>
                                <ns1:timePeriod>
                                    <ns1:end>2024-03-15T00:00:00-07:00</ns1:end>
                                    <ns1:start>2024-03-15T00:00:00-07:00</ns1:start>
                                </ns1:timePeriod>
                            </ns1:IntervalReadings>
                            <ns1:IntervalReadings>
                                <ns1:source>DR</ns1:source>
                                <ns1:value>7.079E0</ns1:value>
                                <ns1:ReadingQualities>
                                    <ns1:ReadingQualityType ref="ACTUAL"/>
                                </ns1:ReadingQualities>
                                <ns1:timePeriod>
                                    <ns1:end>2024-03-16T00:00:00-07:00</ns1:end>
                                    <ns1:start>2024-03-16T00:00:00-07:00</ns1:start>
                                </ns1:timePeriod>
                            </ns1:IntervalReadings>
                            <ns1:ReadingType ref="KWH_DEL"/>
                        </ns1:IntervalBlocks>
                        <ns1:IntervalBlocks>
                            <ns1:IntervalReadings>
                                <ns1:source>DR</ns1:source>
                                <ns1:value>7.855E0</ns1:value>
                                <ns1:ReadingQualities>
                                    <ns1:ReadingQualityType ref="ACTUAL"/>
                                </ns1:ReadingQualities>
                                <ns1:timePeriod>
                                    <ns1:end>2024-03-17T00:00:00-07:00</ns1:end>
                                    <ns1:start>2024-03-17T00:00:00-07:00</ns1:start>
                                </ns1:timePeriod>
                            </ns1:IntervalReadings>
                            <ns1:ReadingType ref="KWH_NET"/>
                        </ns1:IntervalBlocks>
                        <ns1:IntervalBlocks>
                            <ns1:IntervalReadings>
                                <ns1:source>DR</ns1:source>
                                <ns1:value>0.0E0</ns1:value>
                                <ns1:ReadingQualities>
                                    <ns1:ReadingQualityType ref="INVALID"/>
                                </ns1:ReadingQualities>
                                <ns1:timePeriod>
                                    <ns1:end>2024-03-17T00:00:00-07:00</ns1:end>
                                    <ns1:start>2024-03-17T00:00:00-07:00</ns1:start>
                                </ns1:timePeriod>
                            </ns1:IntervalReadings>
                            <ns1:ReadingType ref="KWH_REC"/>
                        </ns1:IntervalBlocks>
                    </ns1:MeterReading>
                </ns1:MeterReadings>
            </ns0:Payload>
        </ns0:Message>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>

XSLT code
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns0="http://www.iec.ch/TC57/2010/schema/message" xmlns:ns1="http://iec.ch/TC57/2011/MeterReadings#" xmlns:n0="http://sap.com/xi/SFIHCM01" version="3.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>  
      <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:template>
      <xsl:template match="ns1:ReadingType[@ref = 'KWH_DEL' ]" />  
</xsl:stylesheet>

I still get the full payload back in result without any filtration, I tried with some different logic but there is no difference in the result, seems it skips the entire logic,

"I still get the full payload back in result without any filtration" That is not the result I get using your code. The element <ns1:ReadingType ref="KWH_DEL"/> on line 30 of your XML is removed. There are no other elements that match your "removing" (i.e. empty) template.

I tried your code (with Saxon 12), the element <ns1:ReadingType ref="KWH_DEL"/> is removed.

Note that if you have <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/> then you don't need the identity transform template.

I think i was not clear in my question, i have edited the question , pls check, thanks. apologies for confusion

Please edit your question again and add the exact expected result.

If you want to remove ns1:IntervalBlocks then make your template match ns1:IntervalBlocks:
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:ns1="http://iec.ch/TC57/2011/MeterReadings#" >
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>  
      
<xsl:template match="ns1:IntervalBlocks[ns1:ReadingType/@ref='KWH_DEL']"/>  

</xsl:stylesheet>

This will remove the ns1:IntervalBlocks element that meets the condition. If you want to keep it and remove all others, then change it to:
<xsl:template match="ns1:IntervalBlocks[ns1:ReadingType/@ref!='KWH_DEL']"/> 

